# How to create a mock object from an interface in Typescript with Jest?

Tags: typescript, mocking, jestjs

I've the following code:

```
import { CreatePageArgs } from 'gatsby';
import { onCreatePage } from './onCreatePage';
jest.mock('gatsby');

describe('on create page', () => {
  test('onCreatePage', () => {
    const pageArgs = {} as CreatePageArgs;
    pageArgs.page.internal.type = 'AnotherType';
    onCreatePage(pageArgs);
  });
});
```

During the execution I get the following error:

```
 FAIL  src/onCreatePage.test.ts
  ● on create page › onCreatePage

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'internal' of undefined

       6 |   test('onCreatePage', () => {
       7 |     const pageArgs = {} as CreatePageArgs;
    >  8 |     pageArgs.page.internal.type = 'AnotherType';
         |                   ^
       9 |     onCreatePage(pageArgs);
      10 |   });
      11 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/onCreatePage.test.ts:8:19)
```

How can I deep instantiate a object from an interface in TypeScript with Jest?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Interfaces are a concept in TypeScript that only exist during compile time. They do not exist during runtime, hence Jest has no way of using it to construct an object.

Comment: Hmm.. I've seen this: https://github.com/marchaos/jest-mock-extended
So it seems to be possible. Why isn't it integrated into jest?